# How to open and read this file from the application cache in android?

Tags: android, file

My application creates a file at this location

Absolute Path

```
/data/user/0/in.eaft.contentsecurityplayer/cache/.\epub\A-Room-with-a-View-morrison.epub\
```

Canonical Path

```
/data/data/in.eaft.contentsecurityplayer/cache/.\epub\A-Room-with-a-View-morrison.epub
```

i need to pass the real path to this [library](https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android) so that it opens the epub file

i need to open this file

```
folioReader.setConfig(config, true)
                    .openBook(filePath);
```

if i pass file path like **/storage/sample.epub** it opens but when i pass the above path file is not opening.

How to open this file from cache directory?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code as it is context based:

```
String cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
```

This will give you the path

Comment: ill try this one

Comment: it gives me this path

Comment: /data/user/0/in.eaft.contentsecurityplayer/cache same as the above